# C++ - QWebView Formatting Url as (string,QUrl)

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to set QwebView's Url as "http://" and other part of url entered from linedit. Here's my function:

```
void MainWindow::on_git_clicked()
{
    QUrl adrs;
    adrs=ui->lineEdit->text();
    ui->webView->setUrl(QUrl("http://" + adrs);
}
```

But it does nothing. But it was working on Python with same way. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this, since your using QUrl and trying to append it to "http://" why not just use a QString instead? this might be your problem

```
QString adrs(ui->lineEdit->text());
ui->webview->setURL(QUrl("http://" + adrs));
```